# Rcpp: Include header from package into cppFunction

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a package that uses `Rcpp`. It has different `C++` function defined int `src/testr.h`. Now at some point I need to generate `Rcpp` functions (using `cppFunction` or `cxxfunction`) that use things defined in `src/testr.h`. How can I do that?

I tried,

```
> cxxfunction(signature(x="list") includes = c('#include "testr.h"'), body=sprintf(template, name, name))
> Rcpp::cppFunction(depends = "testr", includes = c('#include "src/testr.h"'), sprintf(template, name, name))
```

But

```
file7086270f0da.cpp:7:10: fatal error: 'testr.h' file not found
#include "testr.h"

     ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick suggestion:

1. Move the header to `inst/include/testr.h`;
2. This requires a `src/Makevars` entry such as `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include` to have the compilation look there.
3. Now with the package installed as, say, `mypkg`, you can add a `depends="mypkg"` and R will know to set a `-I...` for you.

We use the same trick *all the time* in e.g. [BH](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=BH) and various `Rcpp*` packages.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. I moved the header as you proposed, but I guess because the implementation of a functions from header is still in `src/testr.cpp`, I get following errors like Symbol not found: `__Z7deparseP7SEXPREC`. @dirk-eddelbuettel, do you know how can that be fixed?

Comment: What I suggested assumed a header-only approach (as that was also what the subject of your question suggested).  When you want to import functions from another package and need linking, then a more involved approach is needed.

Comment: The "Writing R Extensions" manual that came with R.  No easy Rcpp wrapper, but you can eg look at how RApiSerialize provides a function for RcppRedis, or how xts provides some functions for RcppXts.  *By far the easiest* is to convert your code to be header-only if you can.